# Cartoon where two young men went on an adventure with some sort of talking animal sidekick looking for a jewel or amulet

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have a distinct memory from my kindergarten class in 1996 in which we watched an animated movie with Native Americans. It was two young men who went on an adventure with some sort of talking animal sidekick. If I remember correctly, they're looking for a jewel or amulet or something like that, and along the way, they fight several giant beasts, including a giant snake.

I seem to remember one of the men saying that the next monster they find "I want to have this one for dinner" when they encounter a snake he is asked again "are you sure you want to have this one for dinner?"

Comment: This sounds familier so it migth have been on in the UK as well.